# Changing an array value in Java method without passing it to method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, class-members

I want to create a function to change a value in an array, but I don't want to pass the array to the function. Here is the part of the code, `data[] array` created at another function.

```
private int[] data;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setPixel(3,2); //I'm not sure at this part?
}

public void setPixel(int i,int x){ 
    data[i] = x; //Is there any possible way to change data[]  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a class around your `main` method and instantiate it within `main`.  You then make `data` a variable of your class and you can access it from within the `setPixel()` method.  This is the proper Object Oriented (OO) way of accomplishing what you're asking.

```
public class Data {
    private int[] data;

    public Data(int size) {
        data = new int[size];
    }

    public void setPixel(int i, int x) {
        data[i] = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data instance = new Data(5);
        instance.setPixel(3, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, which is pretty much like what @zposten provided, but also address's the OP's `data[] array created at another function` requirement:

```
public class EncapsulatedArray
{
    private final int[] data;

    public EncapsulatedArray(final int[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getPixel(final int i)
    {
        return data[i];
    }

    public void setPixel(final int i, final int x)
    {
        data[i] = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }
}
```

To verify and demonstrate, I used:

```
public class EncapsulatedArrayDemo
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final int[] dataFromElsewhere = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

        final EncapsulatedArray ex = new EncapsulatedArray(dataFromElsewhere);

        System.out.println(ex);

        ex.setPixel(2, 7 + ex.getPixel(2));

        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

and obtained the following to console:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 0, 1, 9, 3 }
```

There are various reasons why wrapper classes like this (toy) example are useful, but if you are hoping to "protect" the data array from outside changes (i.e. only `setPixel(int, int)` is allowed to modify values in `data`) then you'll need something more like @zposten's answer which never lets the `data` array object escape from the wrapper. If you do need to use a data array `created at another function` then something like my solution is required - but you'll have to take other steps to ensure that the array isn't fiddled with behind the wrapper's back.